# Перемещение клонированного элемента в другом div

Tags: jquery, html5

Как сделать так, чтобы элементы, которые были помещены в корзину, можно было перемещать по отдельности в самой корзине?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".item").draggable({
    helper: "clone"
  });



  $("#cart_items").droppable({
    accept: ".item",
    activeClass: "drop-active",
    hoverClass: "drop-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var item = ui.draggable.html();
      var itemid = ui.draggable.attr("id");
      var html = '<div class="item icart">';
      html = html + '<div class="divrm">';
      //  html = html + '<a onclick="remove(this)" class="remove '+itemid+'">&times;</a>';
      html = html + '<div/>' + item + '</div>';
      console.log(html);
      $("#cart_items").append(html);


    }
  });



});
```

```css
     font-family:Arial,
     "Free Sans";
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
   }
   #main {
     background: #0099cc;
     margin-top: 0;
     padding: 2px 0 4px 0;
     text-align: center;
   }
   #main a {
     color: #ffffff;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-family: Arial;
   }
   #main a:hover {
     text-decoration: underline;
   }
   #item_container {
     width: 610px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
   }
   .item {
     background: #fff;
     float: left;
     padding: 5px;
     margin: 5px;
     cursor: move;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
     box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
     -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
     -moz-border-radius: .5em;
     border-radius: .5em;
     z-index: 5;
   }
   .title,
   .price {
     display: block;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 14px;
     letter-spacing: -1px;
     font-weight: bold;
     cursor: move;
   }
   .title {
     color: #333;
   }
   .price {
     color: #0099cc;
     margin-top: 5px;
     -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
     -moz-border-radius: .5em;
     border-radius: .5em;
   }
   .icart,
   .icart label {
     cursor: e-resize;
   }
   .divrm {
     text-align: right;
   }
   .remove {
     text-decoration: none;
     cursor: pointer;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 20px;
     position: relative;
     top: -7px;
   }
   .remove:hover {
     color: #999;
   }
   .clear {
     clear: both;
   }
   #cart_container {
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 495px;
   }
   #cart_title span {
     border: 8px solid #666;
     border-bottom-width: 0;
     background: #333;
     display: block;
     float: left;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 11px;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 5px 10px;
     -webkit-border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
     border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
   }
   #cart_toolbar {
     overflow: hidden;
     border: 8px solid #666;
     height: 190px;
     z-index: -2;
     width: 483px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
     border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
     background: #ffffff;
   }
   #cart_items {
     height: 190px;
     width: 483px;
     position: relative;
     padding: 0 0 0 2px;
     z-index: 0;
     cursor: e-resize;
     border-width: 0 2px;
   }
   .back {
     background: #e9e9e9;
   }
   #navigate {
     width: 463px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     border: 8px solid #666;
     border-top-width: 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
     border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
     padding: 10px;
     font-size: 14px;
     background: #333;
     font-weight: bold;
   }
   #nav_left {
     float: left;
   }
   #nav_left a {
     padding: 4px 8px;
     background: #fff;
     -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
     -moz-border-radius: .5em;
     border-radius: .5em;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #0099cc;
   }
   #nav_left a:hover {
     background: #666;
     color: #fff;
   }
   #nav_right {
     float: right;
   }
   .sptext {
     background: #ffffff;
     padding: 4px 8px;
     margin-left: 8px;
     -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
     -moz-border-radius: .5em;
     border-radius: .5em;
     color: #666;
   }
   .count {
     color: #0099cc;
   }
   .drop-active {
     background: #ffff99;
   }
   .drop-hover {
     background: #ffff66;
   }
```

```html
   
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" id="i1">
  <img src="img/1.jpg" />
  <label class="title">Майка 1</label>
  <label class="price">200 р.</label>
</div>
<div class="item" id="i2">
  <img src="img/2.jpg" />
  <label class="title">Майка 2</label>
  <label class="price">240 р.</label>
</div>
<div class="item" id="i3">
  <img src="img/3.jpg" />
  <label class="title">Майка 3</label>
  <label class="price">180 р.</label>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="cart_container">
  <div id="cart_title">
    <span>Корзина покупок</span>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="cart_toolbar">
    <div id="cart_items" class="back"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="navigate">
    <div id="nav_left">
      <a href="" id="btn_clear">Очистить корзину</a>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а вы знаете что  подключили по три версии библиотек?

Comment: да я знаю, но это сути не меняет!

Answer (score 2):

Добавил вызов `sortable`. Заменил класс `item` для элементов в корзине на другой, чтобы на них не обрабатывался `drop` от `droppable`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item").draggable({
    helper: "clone"
  });

  $("#cart_items").droppable({
    accept: ".item",
    activeClass: "drop-active",
    hoverClass: "drop-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $("#cart_items").append(ui.draggable.clone().removeClass("item").addClass("cart_item"));
    }
  }).sortable();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, "Free Sans";
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#main {
  background: #0099cc;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 2px 0 4px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#main a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
}
#main a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#item_container {
  width: 610px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.item, .cart_item {
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: move;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
  -moz-border-radius: .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  z-index: 5;
}
.title,
.price {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: move;
}
.title {
  color: #333;
}
.price {
  color: #0099cc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
  -moz-border-radius: .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
}
.icart,
.icart label {
  cursor: e-resize;
}
.divrm {
  text-align: right;
}
.remove {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: -7px;
}
.remove:hover {
  color: #999;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
#cart_container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 495px;
}
#cart_title span {
  border: 8px solid #666;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
  border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
}
#cart_toolbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 8px solid #666;
  height: 190px;
  z-index: -2;
  width: 483px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cart_items {
  height: 190px;
  width: 483px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 2px;
  z-index: 0;
  cursor: e-resize;
  border-width: 0 2px;
}
.back {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}
#navigate {
  width: 463px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 8px solid #666;
  border-top-width: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
  border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#nav_left {
  float: left;
}
#nav_left a {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
  -moz-border-radius: .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0099cc;
}
#nav_left a:hover {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
}
#nav_right {
  float: right;
}
.sptext {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
  -moz-border-radius: .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  color: #666;
}
.count {
  color: #0099cc;
}
.drop-active {
  background: #ffff99;
}
.drop-hover {
  background: #ffff66;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="item" id="i1">
  <img src="img/1.jpg" />
  <label class="title">Майка 1</label>
  <label class="price">200 р.</label>
</div>
<div class="item" id="i2">
  <img src="img/2.jpg" />
  <label class="title">Майка 2</label>
  <label class="price">240 р.</label>
</div>
<div class="item" id="i3">
  <img src="img/3.jpg" />
  <label class="title">Майка 3</label>
  <label class="price">180 р.</label>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="cart_container">
  <div id="cart_title">
    <span>Корзина покупок</span>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="cart_toolbar">
    <div id="cart_items" class="back"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="navigate">
    <div id="nav_left">
      <a href="" id="btn_clear">Очистить корзину</a>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```